# Заполнить combobox данными из запроса (mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, mvvm

Данный запрос наполняет DataGrid. Можно ли как то из этого же запроса наполнить combobox значениями колонки Manager_History.SIP не изменяя модель и тд.

```
var sips = @"select
                        Manager_History.SIP,
                        Projects.Project_name as Проект,
                        (RTRIM(user_info.firstname) + ' ' + RTRIM(user_info.name)) as Менеджер,
                        Manager_History.date_start,
                        Manager_History.time_start,
                        Manager_History.date_end,
                        Manager_History.time_end                     
                        from Manager
                        LEFT JOIN Manager_History ON(Manager_History.id = (select top 1 Manager_History.id from Manager_History where Manager_History.idmanager = Manager.id order by Manager_History.id desc))
                        LEFT JOIN Projects ON(Projects.id = Manager.idproject)
                        LEFT JOIN Users ON(Users.id = Manager.iduser)
                        LEFT JOIN user_info ON(user_info.id = Users.user_info_id)
                        WHERE((CAST(convert(varchar, Manager_History.date_end, 104) + ' ' + convert(varchar, Manager_History.time_end, 108) AS datetime) >= getdate()) OR Manager_History.date_end = '1900-01-01')
                        order by Manager_History.sip asc";
            var result1 = db.Database.SqlQuery<BusySip>(sips);
            sipGrid.ItemsSource = result1.ToList();
```

Модель:

```
public class BusySip
{
    public Nullable<int> SIP { get; set; }
    public string Проект { get; set; }
    public string Менеджер { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_start { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> time_start { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_end { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> time_end { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Лучше изначально сделать нормальную VM, а не "экономить на спичках". Не откладывайте на потом, т.к. по мере развития проекта внесение таких изменений может стать дороже и сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, можно сделать так:

```
combobox.ItemsSource = result1.Select(x => x.SIP);
```

Но такое ощущение, что это уже не Mvvm, потому что идёт обращение к контролам WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так: 

Создаю коллекцию нужных мне элементов в VM

```
public List<BusySip> BusySips{ get; set; }
```

Потом в разметке XAML привязываю `ItemSource` контрола `ComboBox` эту коллекцию и выбираю нужные мне поля через тег `<Run>`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BusySips}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding SIP}"/>
            </TextBlock>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Для того чтобы узнать выбранный элемент, вы можете добавить `ComboBox'y` свойство `SelectedItem`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BusySips}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBusySip}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding SIP}"/>
            </TextBlock>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

И объявить свойство в вашей VM

```
public BusySip SelectedBusySip{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Тогда уж проще задать `DisplayMemberPath`, чем переопределять `ItemTemplate`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, вы правы, просто я уже привык выбирать несколько полей)